# Estoy realizando un inventario de mis productos para una tienda en linea pero me marca error , ¿que podria hacer?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

Este es el formulario para agregar mis productos no me marca ningun error y por eso no se cual es mi detalle o problema tambien necesito el id del usuario sin embargo no lo estoy agregando por que es un valor auto incrementable no me parece que sea necesario.
*form_productos.php*

```
<?php
    require('conectar.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-sacele=1">
    <title>PRODUCTOS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>AGREGAR PRODUCTOS</h3>
                <form action="agregar_pro2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <p>Producto:</p>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" required="" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control">
                    <BR>
                    <p>Ingresa el precio de venta:</p>
                    <input type="text" name="precio" required="" placeholder="$$$" class="form-control">
                    
                    <br>
                    <p>Foto:</p>
                    <input type="file" name="foto" required="" class="form-control">
                    
                    <br>
                     <p>Ingresa la marca del producto:</p>
                    <input type="text" name="marca" required="" placeholder="marca" class="form-control">

                    <br>
                     <p>Ingresa las existencias:</p>
                    <input type="text" name="existencias" required="" placeholder="existencias" class="form-control">
                    
                    <br>
                    Tipo de contenido:
                    <select name="contenido"  required="" class="form-control">
                        <option>Seleccione...</option>
                        <?php
                               $consulta = $Conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM Contenido");
                               $consulta->execute();
                               $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll();
                               foreach ($resultado as $fila) {
                                   echo '<option value="'.$fila['Id_contenido'].'">'.$fila['Descripcion'].'</option>';
                               }
                            ?>
                    </select>
                    <br>

                    <br>
                    clasificacion:
                    <select name="clasificacion"  required="" class="form-control">
                        <option>Seleccione...</option>
                        <?php
                               $consulta = $Conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM Clasificacion");
                               $consulta->execute();
                               $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll();
                               foreach ($resultado as $fila) {
                                   echo '<option value="'.$fila['Id_clasificacion'].'">'.$fila['Tipo'].'</option>';
                               }
                            ?>
                    </select>
                    <br>

                    <br>
                    Proveedor:
                    <select name="usuario"  required="" class="form-control">
                        <option>Seleccione...</option>
                        <?php
                               $consulta = $Conexion->prepare("SELECT Nombre FROM Usuarios WHERE Id_tipo_usuario = 'TU2'");
                               //$consulta = $Conexion->prepare("SELECT Id_usuario  FROM Usuarios ");
                               $consulta->execute();
                               $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll();
                               foreach ($resultado as $fila) {
                                   echo '<option value="'.$fila['Id_tipo_usuario'].'">'.$fila['Nombre'].'</option>';
                               }
                            ?>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" name="" value="AGREGAR">
</body>
</html>
```

*agregar_pro2.php*

```
<?php
include('conectar.php');
Obtén todos los datos desde el inicio
$nom = $_POST['nombre'];
$pre = $_POST['precio'];
$marca = $_POST['marca'];
$exist = $_POST['existencias'];
$con = $_POST['contenido'];
$clasi = $_POST['clasificacion'];
$pro = $_POST['usuario'];

   $foto = $_FILES['foto'];
    $tmp_name = $foto['tmp_name'];
    $directorio_destino = "images";
     ESTA ES LA CARPETA DESTINO
    $img_file = $foto['name'];
    $destino = $directorio_destino . '/' .  $img_file;
    Continuar solo si el archivo se pudo mover
    if(!move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $destino)) {
         Error moviendo archivo
        } else {
        El archivo se movió correctamente a su ubicación final
        Ahora sí puedes insertar
        $agregar = 'INSERT INTO Productos FROM (Descripcion, Precio, Foto, Marca, Existencias,Id_contenido, Id_clasificacion,id_usuario) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        $res = $Conexion->prepare($agregar);
        Ejecuta la consulta enviando los valores en un arreglo
        $exito = $res->execute([$nom, $pre, $destino, $marca, $exist, $con, $clasi, $pro]);
        if($exito) {
            //echo 'Guardado';
            header('Location: mostrar_pro.php');
        } else {
            echo 'Falló la inserción';
        }
    }

?>
```

Estoy realizando el codigo para realizar mi inventario para un tienda online pero al intentar agregar en los campos de la tabla productos me sale que fallo la insercion pero no me marca ningun
error es la primera vez que realizo esto alguien me podria decir cual es mi detalle ya que no me inserta mis productos.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un error en tu insert:

```
$agregar = 'INSERT INTO Productos FROM (Descripcion, Precio, Foto, Marca, Existencias,Id_contenido, Id_clasificacion,id_usuario) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
```

Me parece que el `FROM` está de más

Comment: Giancarlo Ventura ya he eliminado el insert into pero apesar de eso me aparece "fallo de insercion"

Comment: no se insertan mis productos

Comment: Elimina el FROM, no el insert INTO, sin eso no van a insertarse

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como indica Giancarlo el `FROM` en la sentencia para agregar el producto sería incorrecto.

Además consultando la documentación de la versión actual de PHP, también estarías utilizando inapropiadamente la función de la línea 27:

`$res->execute([$nom, $pre, $destino, $marca, $exist, $con, $clasi, $pro]);`

La función execute no recibe parámetros en el paradigma orientado a objetos, te dejo un link a la documentación [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.execute.php).

La secuencia correcta sería utilizando la función `bind_param` para vincular los parámetros con los que quieres ejecutar tu sentencia sql:

```
$agregar = 'INSERT INTO Productos(Descripcion, Precio, Foto, Marca, Existencias,Id_contenido, Id_clasificacion,id_usuario) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

$res = $Conexion->prepare($agregar);
$res->bind_param($nom, $pre, $destino, $marca, $exist, $con, $clasi, $pro);
$exito = $res->execute();
```

En el enlace de la documentación también encontrarás otros métodos para debuggear mejor tu aplicación.

Un saludo.